# Running a test with Mocha also launches the main program

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to use Mocha to test a CLI app. The tests are running fine but, when I launch the testing procedure, it also launches the main app:

```sh
$ npm run test

> standardize-js@0.2.2 test C:\Users\Gaspard\Documents\Code\standardize-js
> mocha "./source/**/*.spec.js"

? Choose your project language or framework (Use arrow keys) //<-- THIS IS THE PROGRAM
> Javascript 
  Typescript 
  AngularJS 

  Main function //<-- THIS IS THE TEST
    ask if the configuration is valid
Configuration is not valid, terminating program.
      √ should return false if the configuration is not accepted


  1 passing (29ms)
```

I'm kind of new to the testing world and I'm really struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the NPM script used to launch mocha :

```
"test": "mocha \"./source/**/*.spec.js\""
```

Here is my testing method:

```js
/* eslint-disable func-names */
const { expect } = require("chai");

const main = require("./index").test;

describe("Main function", function() {
  describe("ask if the configuration is valid", function() {
    it("should return false if the configuration is not accepted", function() {
      const fakeAnswer = false;

      expect(main.validateConfiguration(fakeAnswer)).to.equal(false);
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my `index.js` file:

```js
function validateConfiguration(answer) {
  if (answer === false) {
    console.log(chalk.red("Configuration is not valid, terminating program."));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const run = async () => {
//MAIN FUNCTION
};

run();

// Export functions and variables to be able to test
exports.test = {
  validateConfiguration
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem with mocha. It is simply now node.js modules work.

When you do this:

```
const main = require("./index").test;
```

Node.js will execute `index.js` and then check the value of `module.exports`. If the module (`index.js`) sets or modifies `module.exports` then node will export it for use by `require()`. But note, in order for node to know that the module has exported anything it **must** execute the javascript file.

Node.js does not have any ability to parse and analyze javascript syntax (that's V8's job). Unlike other languages such as C or Java, modules in node.js are not implemented at the syntax level. Therefore the javascript language does not need to be modified (eg. ES6 modules) for node.js to support modules. Modules are simply implemented as a design pattern.

In your index.js file you call run:

```
run();
```

When `require()` loads `index.js` it will therefore also cause `run()` to be called.

---

### Test libraries, not main

The solution to this is to implement your own logic as modules and test that, not test `index.js`:

`mylib.js`:

```
function validateConfiguration(answer) {
  if (answer === false) {
    console.log(chalk.red("Configuration is not valid, terminating program."));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// Export functions and variables to be able to test
exports.test = { validateConfiguration };
```

`index.js`:

```
const validateConfiguration = require("./mylib").test;

const run = async () => {
    //MAIN FUNCTION
};

run();
```

You can now use your test script as written.

### How can you not test code??

The strategy to keep `index.js` bug free without testing is to remove all logic from it except for the minimum amount of code to wire all your other code up together to run the app. The code should be as simple as "Hello World". That way, the code in main is so small and so simple that you can test it for bugs using your eyeballs.

Any code in `index.js` that causes a bug should be refactored into its own library so that it can be tested separately. There are a small handful of corner cases, such as loading environment variables or opening port 80 where you can't really separate into a library because they literally are wiring logic. For such cases you just have to be really careful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it allowed me to better understand how the JS language works and the best practices to start implementing a test procedure!

Answer (score 0):

It's calling `run` because you are telling it to right after defining the method.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean? I know I'm calling the `run()` function at the end of `index.js`, but why is mocha running it since `run()` is not even defined in `index.spec.js`?